# Resume the previous scroll position

Tags: android

i am using text view in scollview, i wanted to resume it to the previous scrolled position even after the app is closed and restared. and also i want the guidance for resuming the scrolled position wen clicking a button(a botton that ll be available in the first activity and wen that button is clicked it will go to next activity wer the scroll text wiew is available nd the privious scroll position is resumed

my xml code is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:text="@string/ab" /></ScrollView>
```

and my mainactivity java code is

```
package com.example.scroll;
import  android.view.View;

 import android.util.Log;
 import     android.widget.ScrollView;
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm new so i don't know the code that well. You can save the variable for your current scrollposition as a local file when onStop is triggered.
Later when onResume or onCreate is triggered you initialise the scrollposition and viola!